# NodeJS Creating a REST Post API

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, ecmascript-6, crud

I'm trying to learn how to create REST endpoints with NodeJS.

Could you give me an idea of how I'd write the business logic for the following `POST` endpoint?

```
Feature: Add a measurement
  I want to be able to capture a measurement of several metrics at a specific time

  Scenario: Add a measurement with valid (numeric) values
    # POST /measurements
    When I submit a new measurement as follows:
      | timestamp                  | temperature | dewPoint | precipitation |
      | "2015-09-01T16:00:00.000Z" | 27.1        | 16.7     | 0             |
    Then the response has a status code of 201
    And the Location header has the path "/measurements/2015-09-01T16:00:00.000Z"

  Scenario: Cannot add a measurement with invalid values
    # POST /measurements
    When I submit a new measurement as follows:
      | timestamp                  | temperature    | dewPoint | precipitation |
      | "2015-09-01T16:00:00.000Z" | "not a number" | 16.7     | 0             |
    Then the response has a status code of 400

  Scenario: Cannot add a measurement without a timestamp
    # POST /measurements
    When I submit a new measurement as follows:
      | temperature | dewPoint | precipitation |
      | 27.1        | 20       | 0             |
    Then the response has a status code of 400
```

this how I have my `server.js` and `routes.js` setup so far, now I'm wondering how I'd add business logic and the appropriate routing that would comply with the requests above.

```
// server.js
import { createServer } from 'http';
import handler from './routes';

const PORT = +process.env.PORT || 5000;

const server = createServer(handler)
  .on('listening', () => {
    const { port } = server.address();
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
  })
  .on('close', () => console.log('Server closed.'));

server.listen(PORT);
```

```
// routes.js
const server = express();
server.use(parseJsonBody());

server.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('server is running!'));

registerMeasurements(server);
registerStats(server);

export default server;
```

Comment: I edited the post for the other measurement post values to get you started

Answer (score 1):

We used to have to use bodyParser, but now you can use instead of bodyParser

Body parser example

> npm install --save body-parser

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
})); 

app.use(express.json());       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded()); // to support URL-encoded bodies

app.post('/measurement', function(req, res) {
    var timestamp = req.body.timestamp; // Post body value, ex. measurement
    var temperature = req.body.temperature;
});
```

Now we do not have to use bodyParser, we could do the following which is the equivalent

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.multipart());
```

Here is an example for some basic if logic after the post request

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true
}));


app.post(`/mesurement`, (req, res) => {
    var temperature = req.body.temperature;
    let timestamp = req.body.timestamp;
    let dewPoint = req.body.dewpoint;
    let precipitation = req.body.precipitation;
    if (temperature && timestamp && dewPoint && precipitation !== undefined) {
        temperature = parseFloat(temperature);
        dewPoint = parseFloat(dewPoint);
        precipitation = parseFloat(precipitation);
        if (Number.isInteger(temperature)
            && Number.isInteger(dewPoint)
                && Number.isInteger(precipitation)) {
            console.log("We recieved, ", temperature, dewPoint, precipitation)
            res.status(201)
        }
    }

});

app.listen(3000);
```

Test your post endpoints with https://www.getpostman.com

[image]

Comment: could you pls show me how this would look like with the measurements POST requirements and conditions?

Comment: Give me a second, and I will post an example.

Comment: I posted a little example to determine if the temperature post value is an integer, you can expand from there. I suggest using the Postman app for testing post requests.

Comment: awesome thank you so much! So on Postman what would the correct url to test? Would this be correct? `http://localhost:5000/measurements/'what else?`

Comment: You would want to test http://localhost:port/endpoint and then go to the body tab and use url encoded, and set the body value to temperature for the req.body.temperature, and the value to your test value. I added a screenshot of my postman configuration.

Comment: For your status code, just res.status(200) for 200 status code.

Comment: Following your code and then adding the postman as you've suggested `http://localhost:8000/measurements?temperature=122` plus body tab and use url encoded, errors as: ` <pre>Error: Bad Request....</pre>` is the `?` correct on this post call?

Comment: Check app.post('/measurements'); I changed the url to mesurement